# Querying inside Postgresql hstore

Tags: sql, postgresql, hstore

I have a products table which has many variants, variants table has a price column with hstore datatype.

I have two queries

Query 1

```
SELECT variants.* FROM variants WHERE (CAST(variants.price -> 'sg' AS INT) > 1000)
```

Query 2

```
SELECT products.* FROM products INNER JOIN variants ON variants.checkoutable_id = products.id AND variants.checkoutable_type = 'Product' WHERE (CAST(variants.price -> 'sg' AS INT) > 1000)
```

While the first query fails with an error message `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "not a valid number"` the second query works perfectly fine.

Comment: It sounds like you have something in your `price->'sg'` field that isn't a number, but is also only in one or more rows that are not covered by that join. That's just a guess, though, without knowing more about your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building off of my comment, let's figure out how to find the problematic data. I'm going to assume you have an overwhelming number of rows in the `variants` table -- enough rows that manually looking for non-numeric values is going to be difficult.

First, let's isolate the rows which are *not* covered by the second query.

```
SELECT *
FROM variants
WHERE
  checkoutable_type != 'Product' OR
  checkoutable_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM products);
```

That will probably take a while to run, and just be a big data dump. We're really interested in just `price->'sg'`, and specifically the ones where `price->'sg'` isn't a string representation of an integer.

```
SELECT price->'sg'
FROM variants
WHERE
  (checkoutable_type != 'Product' OR
   checkoutable_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM products)) AND
  price->'sg' !~ '[0-9]';
```

That should list out the items not joined in, and which include non-numbers in the string. Clean those up, and your first query should work.

Answer (score 2):

One or more rows of `variants` have improper content for integer, namely `"not a valid number"`. Run the query to check which ones:

```
select *
from variants
where price->'sg' like 'not%';
```